# Shortest way to check if a variable contains positive integer using PHP?

Tags: php, types

I want to check if user input a positive integer number.

```
1    = true
+10  = true
.1   = false
-1   = false
10.5 = false


Just a positive number. 
No characters.
No special character.
No dot.
No minus sign.
```

I tried `is_int()` function but it is returning false even on positive integers. Is there a **string to int** problem?

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524680/check-whether-the-string-is-a-unix-timestamp/2524761#2524761

Comment: what should it return for "+3928742938749283479823749283749" ?

Comment: @stereofrog: textbox length validation may block you for this value in my application :)

Comment: your likely missing stereofrogs point. A signed `Integer` has a range from -2147483648 to 2147483647. Everything before or after that is technically a `float`

Comment: @Gordon: Yes I have got stereofrog's point but I was joking that validation will not allow you to pass integer range :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Something like this should work. Cast the value to an integer and compare it with its original form (As we use `==` rather than `===` PHP ignores the type when checking equality). Then as we know it is an integer we test that it is > 0. (Depending on your definition of positive you may want `>= 0`)

```
$num = "20";

if ( (int)$num == $num && (int)$num > 0 )
```

Comment: @NAVEED It may be because you are doing `int($num)`. Casting is done by surrounding the type you  want to cast to in brackets. In this case `(int)$num`.

Comment: `(int)$num == $num` `(int)'abcde' == 'abcde'` will return true

Comment: What if my $num = "0.2" ; then it returns false... How can I check decimals? My numbers are in the following format "+0.2", "-0.8" ect...

Comment: I solved it this way: `$num = (int)$num >= 0 ? (int)$num : 0;`

Answer (score 31):

**Try the native [Filter function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php)***

```
filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
    'options' => array('min_range' => 1)
));
```

<sup>* if you just want to make sure the input string consists of an arbitrary length digit sequence, use a regex with [0-9] or [\d+]</sup>

**Examples with `filter_var`:**

```
var_dump( filter_var(1, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ); // int(1)

var_dump( filter_var('1', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ); // int(1)

var_dump( filter_var('+10', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ); // int(10)

var_dump( filter_var(.1, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ); // bool(false)

var_dump( filter_var('.1', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ); // bool(false)

var_dump( filter_var(-1, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
    array('options' => array('min_range' => 1))) ); // bool(false)

var_dump( filter_var('-1', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
    array('options' => array('min_range' => 1))) ); // bool(false)

var_dump( filter_var('2147483648', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ); // bool(false)

var_dump( filter_var('0xFF', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ); // bool(false)

var_dump( filter_var(0xFF, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ); // int(255)
```

Comment: and what about abcd, 123d, 10.5 and (space) ??

Comment: @NAVEED try yourself and tell me :) I predict all `false`

Comment: You have to wait.. leaving ;)

Comment: +1: This is how I'd do it but one thing to keep in mind is that 0 won't validate because PHP automatically casts it into false. Use `===` to avoid automatic type casting in evaluation.

Comment: I ran 'abcd', '123d', 10.5, and space (' ') and they all came back as false using simply: 
```if (filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
    echo("Integer is valid");
} else {
    echo("Integer is not valid");
}```

Comment: @user3089840 which is the correct result obviously, since none of the are integers.

Comment: @Gordon Yeah I know - I ran the questions Naveed had posted because I was wondering why he mentioned those, as if they were exceptions and would not work, in case anybody else would like to know that those examples do in fact work right with your method.

Answer (score 3):

I use a regular expression. Very simple if you think about it. You need more punctuation marks if you want to make a number not a whole positive integer (minus sign and a period). So this just makes sure the only thing you have are numbers 0-9 for the value.

```
if(!ereg('^[0-9]+$', $value)) {
  $errors .= "This is not a positive whole number";
}
```

You could add another part on there to make sure it is less than a certain amount of characters as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is the best way

```
if (is_int($num) && $num > 0)
```

as typecasting to an int is very slow.

Comment: But get in mind with this answer that if `$num` is an integer string as `$num = '123'`, `is_int($num)` return `false`

Comment: I use `is_numeric()` to check if the given string is a valid number

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is:

```
if intval($x) > 0 {
 echo "true"
}
```

Comment: intval('1e10'); // 1 and intval('420000000000000000000'); // 2147483647

Answer (score 0):

if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $input)) {

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated