# Question about integers (php)

Tags: php, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Shortest way to check if a variable contains positive integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559923/php-shortest-way-to-check-if-a-variable-contains-positive-integer)

How do I know, is a given variable a number without residue (and not a negative number)?

Like we have numbers (each number is a variable): 5; 6.416; -76; 254.

Its better to have some function, which would give true or false, like:

```
number "5" is true
6.416 is false (has residue "416")
-76 is false
254 is true.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function is_positive_int($n) {
    return $n && abs(intval($n)) == $n;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( (int)$num == $num && (int)$num > 0 ){
  return true;
}
```