# PHP - Check for positive / negative numeric strings

Tags: php

I'd like to know what is the best way to check whether a numeric string is positive or negative.

I am using this [answer on S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559923/shortest-way-to-check-if-a-variable-contains-positive-integer-using-php) but I am not able to determine whether a number with decimals is + or -

For example :

```
function check_numb($Degree){
  if ( (int)$Degree == $Degree && (int)$Degree > 0 ) {
    return 'Positive';
} else {
    return 'Negative';
  }
}

print check_numb("+2"); // returns Positive
print check_numb("+2.0"); // returns Positive
print check_numb("+2.1"); // returns Negative ??
print check_numb("+0.1"); // returns Negative ??
print check_numb("-0.1"); // returns Negative
```

It seems when a decimal is added it returns false. How do you properly check for positive strings `> +0.XX` and negative `< -0.XX`  which 2 decimals..

Thanks!

Comment: `(int)"+2.1" ==  2` and `2 != "+2.1"` - For ALL numbers, if it is < 0 it is negative and if it is > 0 it is positive.

Comment: I understand but given a $numb= "+0.8" ; then (int)$numb returns 0 instead of 0.8, it returns negative. how could I return the (int) with decimals, does this sounds logic?

Comment: `.8` is NOT an integer!  `0 != "+0.8"`.  Also, `0` NOT `> 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because: `(int)"+2.1" == 2` and `2 != "+2.1"`.  For ALL numbers, if it is `< 0` it is negative and if it is `> 0` it is positive.  If it is `== 0`, then it is obviously `0` which is unsigned.

```
function check_numb($Degree){
  if ( $Degree > 0 ) {
    return 'Positive';
} elseif( $Degree < 0 ) {
    return 'Negative';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering the given input, why not :

```
$number = '+2,33122';
$isPositive = $number[0] === '+' ? 'Positive' : 'Negative';
// Positive

$number = '-0,2';
$isPositive = $number[0] === '+' ? 'Positive' : 'Negative';
// Negative
```

Here is a more generic code, working even if the sign is removed from your input :

```
function checkPositive ($number) {
   if (!is_numeric(substr($number, 0, 1))) {
       $sign = substr($number, 0, 1);
       return $sign == '+';
   }
   return $number > 0;
} 


$number = '+2,33122';
var_dump(checkPositive($number));
// true

$number = '-2,33122';
var_dump(checkPositive($number));
// false

$number = '2,22';
var_dump(checkPositive($number));
// true
```

Comment: I assume this method will always require numeric string to start either with the + or - signs. Right ?

Comment: @Awena Yes. I added a function that will work in any case : with or without a sign before the numeric value