# Checking if a string contains an integer

Tags: php, validation

Do you know of a function that can check if a string contains an integer?

Here's how I'd expect it to work:

```
holds_int("23") // should return true.  
holds_int("2.3") // should return false.  
holds_int("qwe") // should return false.
```

Comment: *(related)* [Check whether the string is a unix timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524680/check-whether-the-string-is-a-unix-timestamp/2524761#2524761) - the test is basically the same

Comment: @mathk: I need to validate user input.

Comment: And what input exactly is considered valid?

Comment: Do you consider '1.0', '0xFF' or '0123' (octal) as integers for the test and what if you pass in an integer instead of a string?

Comment: @Gumbo: Any natural number would be considered valid input in the case I'm working on.

Comment: @Emanuil do you consider natural numbers to extend beyond PHP's integer bit range? E.g. does 2147483648 qualify?

Comment: @Emanuil: Any natural number or any natural number that can be represented by PHP’s integer data type?

Comment: I guess it's any natural number that can be represented by PHP’s integer data type.

Comment: this already exists in php its http://www.php.net/is_numeric

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
if((string)(int)$var == $var) {
    echo 'var is an integer or a string representation of an integer';
}
```

Example results:

```
var_dump( test(1)             ); // TRUE
var_dump( test('1')           ); // TRUE
var_dump( test('1.0')         ); // TRUE
var_dump( test('1.1')         ); // false
var_dump( test('0xFF')        ); // false
var_dump( test('0123')        ); // TRUE
var_dump( test('01090')       ); // TRUE
var_dump( test('-1000000')    ); // TRUE
var_dump( test('+1000000')    ); // TRUE
var_dump( test('2147483648')  ); // false
var_dump( test('-2147483649') ); // false
```

See Gordon's answer below for how this would behave differently if `===` were used for comparison instead of `==`.

Comment: this should test with `===` and make sure the number is inside the integer range

Comment: === won't work if $var actually is an integer. == will, regardless of whether it is a string or an int. OP didn't ask for that specifically, but it seems a bit perverse to return false if it actually is an integer.

Comment: There's also no point in the additional check for the PHP_INT_MAX -- the above will return false if the integer is out of range anyway. Why add the additional check?

Comment: I dont think so: the OP asked for if *string* holds *integer*. If you pass in an integer, it's not a string, so ...

Comment: @Gordon: Casting to integer will always yield a valid integer.

Comment: @Gumbo Ok, I stand corrected. You dont need the bitrange check then. And let's leave it up to the OP to decide if he needs `===` or `==` comparison. There is edge cases, e.g. '1.0', hex and octals.

Comment: I'd rather do something like `(string)(int)$var === (string)$var`, to eliminate what I see as a false positive in your list, `1.0`.

Comment: @nyson, you should make that an answer so I could vote for it.

Comment: `var_dump( test('2147483648')  ); // false
var_dump( test('-2147483649') ); // false` both return true, not false.

Comment: Except 0123 is an int

Answer (score 14):

Not the fastest method, but [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var) is quite accurate:

```
function test($s)
{
    return filter_var($s, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false;
}
```

Here are the results based on Jhong's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3377560/1338292), differences marked with `!!`:

```
var_dump(test(1)            ); // true
var_dump(test('1')          ); // true
var_dump(test('1.0')        ); // false !!
var_dump(test('1.1')        ); // false
var_dump(test('0xFF')       ); // false
var_dump(test('0123')       ); // false !!
var_dump(test('01090')      ); // false !!
var_dump(test('-1000000')   ); // true
var_dump(test('+1000000')   ); // true
var_dump(test('2147483648') ); // true !! on 64bit
var_dump(test('-2147483649')); // true !! on 64bit
```

To allow octal integers:

```
function test($s)
{
   return filter_var($s, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_OCTAL) !== false;
}
```

Results:

```
var_dump(test('0123') ); // true
var_dump(test('01090')); // false !!
```

To allow hexadecimal notation:

```
function test($s)
{
   return filter_var($s, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_HEX) !== false;
}
```

Results:

```
var_dump(test('0xFF')); // true !!
```

Comment: I just used your function and it has problems with large numbers. Given the fact that the requirement is to check if a string contains an integer, but doesn't say how long can it be, I believe that a regular expression approach might be better in this case.

For a number like 999999999999999999 it will work, but if you try for instance with a string containing the number 9999999999999999999, which is a valid integer, it will fail.

Comment: @JeanPaulRuiz sure, that's one way of interpretation, my method checks whether it can be assigned to a variable :)

Answer (score 11):

Dont want to accidently turn Jhong's answer into a CW, so for the record here is the results when testing with `===` instead of `==`.

```
function test($var) {
    return ((string)(int)$var === $var);
}

var_dump( test(1)             ); // returns false vs TRUE
var_dump( test('1')           ); // returns TRUE
var_dump( test('1.0')         ); // returns false vs TRUE
var_dump( test('1.1')         ); // returns false 
var_dump( test('0xFF')        ); // returns false
var_dump( test('0123')        ); // returns false vs TRUE
var_dump( test('-0123')       ); // returns false vs TRUE
var_dump( test('-1000000')    ); // returns TRUE
var_dump( test('+1000000')    ); // returns false vs TRUE
var_dump( test('2147483648')  ); // returns false
var_dump( test('-2147483649') ); // returns false
```

Comment: 1.0 (float) and 0123 (invalid) are better results here than my version -- I hadn't considered them!

Comment: @Jhong using `==` will also return true for hex `0xFF` and scientific notation `-1.3e3` (e.g. both when not used as string, false if used as string)

Answer (score 9):

> **Update** Since PHP 7.1 there are problems with using `is_int()` with non-numeric values, as discussed in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered/42044413#42044413). In any case, this is a very old answer and I'd really view it as something of a hack at this point so YMMV ;)

Sorry if this question has been answered but this has worked for me in the past:

First check if the string `is_numeric`. if it is add a `0` to the value to get PHP to covert the string to its relevant type. Then you can check if it's an int with `is_int`. Quick and dirty but it works for me...

```
$values = array(1, '2', '2.5', 'foo', '0xFF', 0xCC, 0644, '0777');

foreach ($values as $value) {
  $result = is_numeric($value) && is_int(($value + 0)) ? 'true' : 'false';
  echo $value . ': ' . $result . '<br />';
}
```

Results:

```
1: true
2: true
2.5: false
foo: false
0xFF: true
204: true
420: true
0777: true
```

The only problem is that it will evaluate octal values wrapped in a string literally, i.e: '0123' will simply become 123. But that's easy to address :)

Comment: When a value is not actually a number, such as `foo`, I get the following *PHP error*: `A non-numeric value encountered`. I am using `PHP 7.1.3`. [An answer related to this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42044413/1883256). And [They advice not to use is_int() here](https://odd.blog/2009/03/31/php-is_numeric-vs-is_int/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Pathros - as you can see this is a 7 year old answer, so it looks like there is a change in behaviour since PHP 7.1. I'll edit my answer to make note of the change.

Answer (score 6):

`ctype_digit` will do the trick:

`ctype_digit($str)`

1. `$str` has to be a string
2. extra spaces are not allowed
3. no decimal points `.`

Answer (score 4):

Other option

```
function holds_int($str)
   {
   return preg_match("/^-?[0-9]+$/", $str);
   }
```

Comment: This (in its current form) also doesn't account for negative integers.

Comment: regex is a fairly resource-intensive solution to an ostensibly simple problem (I didn't downvote you mind).

Comment: Now your regex allows `12-34`. You should use `/^-?[0-9]+$/`. If you want to reject leading zeros (which you should) use `/^-?[1-9][0-9]*$/`.

Comment: good point about the minus in the middle, updated the code!
NB: I wasn't complaining because of the downvote per se, just asking why it was not correct. As for regexp being resource intensive it really depends how often this gets called, it may not be good in certain situation but it may be absolutely ok for others.

Comment: @nikic: I wouldn't reject leading zeros, "05" is a valid integer containing string IMHO.

Comment: Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems

Answer (score 4):

If the string contains spaces, then @Jack's answer will not provide accurate result.
e.g.

```
$var = '19   ';
if((string)(int)$var == $var) {
echo 'var is an integer or a string representation of an integer';
}
```

The above string will not be an int according to the above check.

So instead of using this, try following:

```
if(ctype_digit(trim('19  '))){
    echo 'it is digit ';
}else{
    echo 'it is not digit ';
}
```

Comment: Actually, my answer yields `true` for `"19    "`; you must be confused with Jhong's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this since long time. While all the other answers have drawbacks or special cases, if you want to detect any possible int valued thing, including 1.0 "1.0" 1e3 "007" then you better **let is_numeric do its job** to detect any possible PHP object that represents a number, and only then check if that number is really an int, converting it to int and back to float, and testing if it changed value.:

```
function isIntValued($var) {
    if(is_numeric($var)) { // At least it's number, can be converted to float
        $var=(float)$var; // Now it is a float
        return ((float)(int)$var)===$var;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

or in short

```
function isIntValued($var) {
    return (!is_numeric($var)?FALSE:((float)(int)(float)$var)===(float)$var);
}
```

Or

```
 function isIntValued($var) {
    return (is_numeric($var) && ((float)(int)(float)$var)===(float)$var);
}
```

Note that while PHP's `is_int()` checks if the **type** of variable is an integer, on the contrary the other standard PHP function `is_numeric()` determines very accurately if the **contents of the variable** (i.e. string chars) **can** represent a number.

If, instead, you want "1.0" and "2.00" not to be considered integers but floats (even if they have an integer value), then the other answer ( @Darragh Enright )  using is_numeric, adding zero and testing for int is probably the most correct solution:

```
    is_numeric($s) && is_int($s+0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will also help in given situation
there is a function in php that already does this, its called "is_numeric()"
it will return true or false accordenly..

```
   if(is_numeric($somestring) == True){
        echo "this string contains a integar";
    }
```

link: http://www.php.net/is_numeric

you said "holdsint("2") should return true, well is_numeric("2") returns True, and is_numeric("a") False, as expected, this function exists in php, no need to rewrite.

Comment: This is incorrect; `is_numeric()` returns `true` for floats.

Comment: ahh yes but like most things here, at the time of post it was correct for original question didnt mention floats, then the original poster went and edited his question so now i look like the idiot. Typical.

Answer (score 0):

There may be two cases-

1. You need to check for exact string format of a number(most of ans is about this one)
2. You want to check, whether a string contains a specific number or not

   `preg_match('/'.$matching_number.'/',$container_string);`

Answer (score 0):

comparison.php:

```
<?php
function is_numeric_int($s)
{
  return (strval(intval($s)) === $s);
}

function print_ini($s)
{
  echo "$s: " . ( is_numeric_int($s) ? 'true' : 'false' ) . "\n";
}

print_ini('qwe');
print_ini('23');
print_ini('-23');
print_ini('23.0');
print_ini('-23.0');
?>
```

Test run:

```
$ php comparison.php 
qwe: false
23: true
-23: true
23.0: false
-23.0: false
```

Comment: Except 0123 is an int

Comment: @FrancescoMM Ouch. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I liked nyson's suggestion, but noticed that it will be false for '0123'.
I'm now doing this:

```
(string)(int)$var === ltrim((string)$var, '0')
```

(This would have been posted as a comment @nyson, but I don't have enough privileges to do that yet).

Edited to add:
If you want zero to be true, you need to do something like

```
(int)$var === 0 || (string)(int)$var === ltrim((string)$var, '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Assert library in you project (https://github.com/beberlei/assert) you can easily do it in one line:

```
Assertion::integerish($var);
```

**Note: it throws an exception in case of violation the assertion.**

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you are searching for a value in a string, I'd go for:

```
(bool) preg_match('/^\d+$/', '23'); // true
(bool) preg_match('/^\d+$/', '2.3'); // false
(bool) preg_match('/^\d+$/', 'qwe'); // false
```

Answer (score -3):

`is_int` is the only what it's meant to do this work.

Comment: `is_int` determines if the _type_ of the variable is an integer, not the _value_.