# I want my form input as an integer... but only if it was submitted as such

Tags: php, string, casting, integer

Since it appears [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) only returns `0` if it's not an integer (and I want 0 sometimes in the input), and also since [is_int](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) doesn't evaluate string input to tell me if it's an integer (and I'm simply not familiar with what casting a variable as `(int)` does if it's not an integer).

What's the correct way to go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a string holds an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377537/checking-if-a-string-holds-an-integer)

Comment: I suppose it is.  I'll just use `if((string)(int)$var == $var)` then.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [**`ctype_digit()`**](https://www.php.net/ctype_digit) function *(quoting)* :

> `bool ctype_digit ( string $text )`
>
> Returns `TRUE` if every character
> in the string `$text` is a decimal
> digit, `FALSE` otherwise.

Using this to test what the input is made of, you should then be able to decide what to do with it, depending on the fact it contains an integer or not.

I suppose something like this should do the trick :

```
if (ctype_digit($_POST['your_field'])) {
    // it's an integer => use it
} else {
    // Not an integer
}
```

Comment: I'm out of votes, so have a textual +1.  Everyone always forgets about poor old ctype.

Comment: Yeah, it's not quite well-known, it seems : I've had this same questions a few days ago from a colleague, at work ^^

Comment: Guess this could work, but I'm using `if((string)(int)$var == $var)` from the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [is_numeric](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). According to the examples in the documentation, this is exactly what you want.

Comment: While `is_numeric` works on strings, it also returns true for things that convert into floats.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use is_int in conjunction with [is_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php)?

For example:

```
if(is_int(x) == 0 && is_string(x))
```

Comment: No. A variable cannot be of type string and of type int at the same time. The expression you quote is true if `x` is a string and false otherwise—not at all what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input =  preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,}$/",$input) ? (int)$input:$input;
```

Comment: \d matches decimal digits. http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php   \d is the same thing as [0-9]

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as matt but easier to read:

```
preg_match('/^\d+$/', $x)
```

But `ctype` is probably faster if your system has it.