# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php

Recently updated to PHP 7.1 and start getting following error

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in on line 29

Here is what line 29 looks like

```
$sub_total += ($item['quantity'] * $product['price']);
```

On localhost all works fine..

Any ideas how to tackle this or what it is ?

Comment: `var_dump($item['quantity'], $product['price'])`

Comment: Looks like a new warning in PHP 7 (as you are aware). http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.other-changes.php

When you get the error do those variables have values?  I think you could avoid it by initializing them to 0.

Comment: @MichaelHanon where is the answer you are referring to? what is the syntax error?

Comment: $sub_total += ((int)$item['quantity'] * (int)$product['price']);

Comment: i use legacy format like this  a=a+b; or  str=str."<a href='".str2."'>asd</a>"; or $this->storeItems = $this->storeItems . $str;

Comment: This question needs additional diagnostic/debugging details.  Showing your code and the warning is not painting the whole picture.  We don't know what your exact input data is.  You will notice that your question is so vague that answers are actually guessing at what your input is.  **Off-topic: Needs Debugging Details**  See u_mulder's comment.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

It seems that in PHP 7.1, a Warning will be emitted if a non-numeric value is encountered. See this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.other-changes.php).

Here is the relevant portion that pertains to the Warning notice you are getting:

> New E_WARNING and E_NOTICE errors have been introduced when invalid
> strings are coerced using operators expecting numbers or their
> assignment equivalents. An E_NOTICE is emitted when the string begins
> with a numeric value but contains trailing non-numeric characters, and
> **an E_WARNING is emitted when the string does not contain a numeric
> value.**

I'm guessing either `$sub_total`,  `$item['quantity']` or `$product['price']` does not contain a numeric value, so you need to start debugging them, for example,

```
var_dump($sub_total, $item['quantity'], $product['price']);
```

and see which one is wrong and then fix the source of incorrect value.

When dealing with user input, make sure that values contain a numeric value before processing them. Maybe use some sort of conditional before calculating the $sub_total, like so:

```
<?php

if (!is_numeric($item['quantity']) || is_numeric($product['price'])) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Price or quantity does not contain a numeric value"); 
} 
$sub_total += $item['quantity'] * $product['price'];
```

Only in a rare case, when you positively know that some certain non-numeric value can be used in calculations, you may cast it to numeric type. For example, in some legacy code an empty string can be used in calculations, which was silently cast to `0` in previous PHP versions. Here you can add a condition for this exact value:

```
$item['quantity'] = ($item['quantity'] === "" ? 0 : $item['quantity']);
$sub_total += $item['quantity'] * $product['price'];
```

this code will bypass an empty string but would warn you, if any other unexpected value will be encountered.

Better still, just make sure that `$item['quantity']` is always of numeric type, preferably by using [PHP's type hinting system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php).

Comment: I had this issue because I still had a few plus signs in the asp I was transferring to PHP. Ctrl+f and look for + characters.

Comment: Is there a way to turn this warning off via php.ini?

Comment: @BeniRose The warning will only be thrown if your trying to apply math to non-numeric values, so if you try to multiply the strings 'cat' * '10', it will throw the error. If you try '10' * '10', you'll get no warning and the int 100. Turning this one off might be a bad idea I think. Here are a few links to PHP docs that may help you if you want to turn this off though. http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting
http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on a legacy Symfony 1.4 project, and it seems there's a few places this happens intentionally, which has been a pain. This really should be a flag in php.ini that allows you to turn off this level of strictness.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `$sub_total += ((int)$item['quantity'] * (int)$product['price']);`

Comment: To be fair, I wouldn't turn this off, its one of the more useful warnings that can actually lead you to find a bug - in our case, one that had been in place for years and not noticed. As Daniel said, it only appears if you try and apply maths to a non numeric string. I fail to see a case where this would be the desired behaviour.

i.e.  "default" * 86400 would equal 0 and without this warning, you'd never know unless you happen to step through the code.

Comment: I got this error when I wrote SQL query and used $query += "...." instead: $query .= "...."
Just thought same thing like JS :)

Comment: I took the liberty to amend the code, as this question become a reference, hence most obvious steps had to be added. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 450):

Not exactly the issue you had but the same error for people searching.

This happened to me when I spent too much time on JavaScript.

Coming back to PHP I concatenated two strings with `+` instead of `.` and got that error.

Comment: Very similar issue for me I made `echo "myString".count($myArray)+$i."myString2";`, but the brackets were needed:  `echo "myString".(count($myArray)+$i)."myString2";`

Answer (score 68):

> ***Community warning:*** use the following answer at your own risk. Casting values unconditionally may lead to unexpected results. `$a = "1,5";$b = 2; echo (int)$a * (int)$b;` would silently give you 2. `$a = "$1500";$b = 2; echo (int)$a * (int)$b;` would silently give you *zero*.

You can solve the problem without any new logic by just casting the thing into the number, which prevents the warning and is equivalent to the behavior in PHP 7.0 and below:

```
$sub_total += ((int)$item['quantity'] * (int)$product['price']);
```

(The answer from Daniel Schroeder is not equivalent because $sub_total would remain unset if non-numeric values are encountered. For example, if you print out $sub_total, you would get an empty string, which is probably wrong in an invoice. - by casting you make sure that $sub_total is an integer.)

Comment: that's a bad practice. You need to filter your inputs

Comment: This seems to be the best answer. And for all you know these values are coming from the database, you may not need to escape.

Comment: @Ciro Vargas: It depends on the application. In many cases you want an undefined integer to be interpreted as zero. Anyway this is the equivalent of the PHP7.0 behavior and does not require a rewrite of the code. (The accepted answer does require a rewrite.)

Comment: @RolandSeuhs I'm not sure I follow, when multiplying two strings, '24' * '10' will produce 240 in PHP, '24' * null will produce 0, but '24' * 'cat' will throw the error mentioned above because 'cat' is a non-numeric value. You can cast 'cat' to an int, but that won't give you a meaningful subtotal either. As for my solution, it works for determining whether quantity and price are numeric. If they are strings '24' and '10', it passes, but if either is a non-numeric string, it fails. How sub_total gets dealt with was not really my aim, sorry if it came off that way.

Comment: @Daniel: Your solution requires additional code, which means it can introduce new bugs. When you upgrade from PHP from any version to version 7.1., you usually want the same behavior as in the old version - and that is a cast to integer. Therefore you are pretty much guaranteed that the software still works as intended, written and tested.

Comment: @Daniel: In other words: 24 * 'cat' equals 0 in all versions of PHP (including 7.1. - it is just a warning after all) - adding a cast to integer does not change the logic of the code and thus does not require retesting of the software, but your solution does (which can be expensive).

Comment: bear in mind if price is a float, the above code will have unintended side effects. I know its more code, but I'd check to see if they were numeric and default them to 0 if not before running the above code (without the int casts)

Comment: ***** *PRICE* should be (float) should put that!

Comment: Adding the brackets alone resolved the issue for me. I didn't need to type cast them.

Comment: Yes, I used + instead of dot for concatination

Comment: @RolandSeuhs amazing answer .without any waisting time about how php works or why sky is blue (smh), tnx man

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue with my pagination forward and backward link .... simply set (int ) in front of the variable $Page+1 and it worked...

```
<?php 
$Page = (isset($_GET['Page']) ? $_GET['Page'] : '');
if ((int)$Page+1<=$PostPagination) {
?>
<li> <a href="Index.php?Page=<?php echo $Page+1; ?>"> &raquo;</a></li>
<?php }
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

This was happening to me specifically on PHPMyAdmin. So to more specifically answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282813/phpmyadmin-error-when-selecting-rows-from-table?noredirect=1&lq=1), I did the following:

In File:

```
C:\ampps\phpMyAdmin\libraries\DisplayResults.class.php
```

I changed this:

```
// Move to the next page or to the last one
$endpos = $_SESSION['tmpval']['pos']
    + $_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows'];
```

To this:

```
$endpos = 0;
if (!empty($_SESSION['tmpval']['pos']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['tmpval']['pos'])) {
    $endpos += $_SESSION['tmpval']['pos'];
}
if (!empty($_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows'])) {
    $endpos += $_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows'];
}
```

Hope that save's someone some trouble...

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the issue in phpmyadmin with PHP 7.3. Thanks @coderama, I changed libraries/DisplayResults.class.php line 855 from

```
// Move to the next page or to the last one
$endpos = $_SESSION['tmpval']['pos']
    + $_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows'];
```

into

```
// Move to the next page or to the last one
$endpos = (int)$_SESSION['tmpval']['pos']
    + (int)$_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows'];
```

Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

### PHP 7.1-7.4

This warning happens when you have a non-numeric string in an expression (probably `+`, `-`, `*`, or `/`) where PHP is expecting to see another scalar (int, float, or bool). There are two likely situations where this happens:

- You did not mean to use an operation that expects a scalar. For example, `+` (addition) when you meant `.` (concatenation).
- You were expecting a number, but the value you used was not even close to a number. Figure out what your non-number is, and handle accordingly.

  - For example, if you have `echo 3 + $variable` and your `$variable` is the string `"n/a"`, then you might decide to instead echo "not applicable". Or maybe you decide that all non-numeric values should be treated as 0 and cast to the .

Fix these warnings! In PHP 8, this becomes a fatal error: "Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types".

### PHP 8

Code that used to produce the warning "A non well formed numeric value encountered" in PHP 7.1-7.4 now gives this warning instead. This happens when you have a "trailing string", which is a string that starts with a number, but is followed by something non-numeric. (It will still do the math but you should fix this! In the future it may be upgraded to an error.) For example:

```php
echo 3 + "30 meters";
```

Output:

> **Warning**:  A non-numeric value encountered in **[...][...]** on line **X**
> 33

Comment: @YourCommonSense The alleged "fix" wasn't added by me but an editor, and I've now rolled it back. (I know how PHP treats numbers and casting and purposefully left that out.)

Comment: Beg my pardon. Deleting the comment

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
$sub_total = 0;
```

and within your loop now you can use this

```
$sub_total += ($item['quantity'] * $product['price']);
```

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you're not incrementing with some variable that its value is an empty string like ''.

Example:

```
$total = '';
$integers = range(1, 5);

foreach($integers as $integer) {
    $total += $integer;
}
```

Comment: Super, this is a case missed in most of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

For others that answers here may not resolve the issue.

My issue didn't involve integers or concatenation.

My problem was a simple typo (an errant string in my code).

```
$conn = new PDO($details, $username, $password); -
```

Somehow I had entered a minus sign (-) in my code accidentally.  Removing this fixed my issue.  My guess is that PHP was erroring because since it saw the minus sign it expected it needed to perform some arithmetic there but there were no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

For me this happened right now because of the operator precedence. I wrote `$something & BITMASK && $another_value` and the binding of `&&` was "tighter" than the one of `&`. Always make sure to use parentheses to avoid such problems!

Comment: Idem... but with me it was the even simpler typo of "&" instead of "&&" acting on a string.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at this page as I had this issue. For me I had floating point numbers calculated from an array but even after designating the variables as floating points the error was still given, here's the simple fix and example code underneath which was causing the issue.

Example PHP

```
<?php
$subtotal = 0; //Warning fixed
$shippingtotal = 0; //Warning fixed

$price = array($row3['price']);
$shipping = array($row3['shipping']);
$values1 = array_sum($price);
$values2 = array_sum($shipping);
(float)$subtotal += $values1; // float is irrelevant $subtotal creates warning
(float)$shippingtotal += $values2; // float is irrelevant $shippingtotal creates warning
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sn = 0;//increment the serial number, then add the sn to job
for($x = 0; $x<20; $x++)
{
$sn++;
$added_date = "10/10/10";
$job_title = "new job";
$salary = $sn*1000;
$cd = "27/10/2017";//the closing date
$ins = "some institution";//the institution for the vacancy 
$notes = "some notes here";//any notes about the jobs

$sn_div = "<div class='sn_div'>".$sn."</div>";
$ad_div = "<div class='ad_div'>".$added_date."</div>";
$job_div = "<div class='job_div'>".$job_title."</div>";
$salary_div = "<div class='salary_div'>".$salary."</div>";
$cd_div = "<div class='cd_div'>".$cd."</div>";//cd means closing date
$ins_div = "<div class='ins_div'>".$ins."</div>";//ins means institution
$notes_div = "<div class='notes_div'>".$notes."</div>";


/*erroneous line*/$job_no = "job"+$sn;//to create the job rows
$$job_no = "<div class='job_wrapper'>".$sn_div.$ad_div.$job_div.$salary_div.$cd_div.$ins_div.$notes_div."</div>";

echo $$job_no;//and then echo each job

}
```

that's the code I had which looped and created new html div elements. The code worked fine and the elements were formed, but i got the same warning in the error_log.

After reading the useful other answers, I figured that I was summing up a string and a number in the erroneous line. So I changed the code at that line to

```
/*erroneous line*/$job_no = "job"&&$sn;//this is the new variable that will create the job rows
```

Now the code works as earlier but with no warnings this time. Hope this example would be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Solve this error on WordPress

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\aad-2\wp-includes\SimplePie\Parse\Date.php on line 694

Simple solution here!

1. locate a file of `wp-includes\SimplePie\Parse\Date.php`
2. find a line no. 694
3. you show the code `$second = round($match[6] + $match[7] / pow(10, strlen($match[7])));`
4. and change this 3.) to this line `$second = round((int)$match[6] + (int)$match[7] / pow(10, strlen($match[7])));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sub_total_price = 0; 

foreach($booking_list as $key=>$value) {
        $sub_total_price += ($price * $quantity); 
}

echo $sub_total_price;
```

it's working 100% :)

Answer (score 0):

That's happen usually when you con-cat strings with + sign. In PHP you can make concatenation using dot sign (.) So sometimes I accidentally put + sign between two strings in PHP, and it show me this error, since you can use + sign in numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late but for those who still have been banging their head around like I was. In my case it was legacy project developed in PHP 5.6 but when I need to modify it I was running PHP 7.1. I didn't bother to change it.(Had to pay for it) So the issue is **PHP 7.1 is more strict than PHP 5.6**

In PHP 5.6 following is allowed.

```
$totalPrice = ' '
$someFoo = $totalPrice + 100
// This is totally fine. And PHP will not yell about it.
```

While in PHP 7.1 it will throw an error

```
$totalPrice = ' '
$someFoo = $totalPrice + 100
// Error : A non-numeric value encountered.
```

So after changing that line to `$totalPrice = 0` everything worked.

Hope someone will find it useful.

Answer (score -1):

I received this error after adding two formatted variables using the [number_format()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp) method. The reason is because this method usually formats your number with a `,` unless you specified the optional *separator* argument as `null`. For example, let's say I have the following code:

```
$subtotal = 6556.7;
$vat = number_format(0.175 * $subtotal, 2);            // 1,147.42
$transactionfee = number_format(0.02 * $subtotal, 2);  // 131.13
$total = $subtotal + $vat + $transactionfee;           // 6556.7 + 1,147.42 + 131.13 = ERROR
```

This would trigger the following error because one of the variables contains a `,` which is invalid for a float type:

> **Warning**: A non-numeric value encountered ...

The `number_format()` method has the following method signature:

> `number_format(number,decimals,decimalpoint,separator)`.

By specifying the separator argument as `''`, this error could be fixed as follows:

```
$subtotal = 6556.7;
$vat = number_format(0.175 * $subtotal, 2, '.', '');           //1147.42
$transactionfee = number_format(0.02 * $subtotal, 2, '.', ''); //131.13
$total = $subtotal + $vat + $transactionfee;   // // 6556.7 + 1147.42 + 131.13 = 7835.25
```

Comment: Or just not format your numbers to strings if you want to do further arithmetic with them…‽

Comment: That's a short-sighted way of viewing things. Every case is different. 

There are cases like in my case, when you need 2 decimal places for printing output. You can't just plug everything in with arithmetic and output it directly to the user.  Otherwise, when you print it, it won't make sense on the screen because of the dozens of digits after the decimal point. 

@deceze

Comment: Exactly. Format the number **on output**, and not before. Don't try to store formatted numbers internally that you still need to do arithmetic.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone. I have had:

```php
<?php echo $data['style_headerheight']-3; ?>
```

which gave the error:

> PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in framework/inc/customcss.php on line 78

To fix, I replaced that by:

```php
<?php echo ((int)$data['style_headerheight']-(int)3); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same weird case. On my book, what happend is i did, for example:

```
$bla = '';
```

and later on i had an if condition, and if the condition is met, then $bla would have gotten some numeric value. but again, only if the condition is met. I knew for 100% that the condition would met, so... after that if condition, i used $bla once again and walla - got the warning.

As i see it, PHP gave warning because i reseted the variable as string. i did not mind doing that because i knew for 100% that the next if condition would assign some numeric value to $bla, but PHP don't know what i knew. Meaning, he assumed that the if condition might not get triggered, and then the '' would stay at $bla, and later on when trying to assign $bla to $i (for a loop) => i got the notice. Again, that was my case. assigning $bla = 0 instead of $bla = '' did the job, but it is more of the idea behind it. Hope it helps anyone.

Comment: Nevertheless, assigning an empty string to a supposedly numeric variable is not the best idea

Answer (score -1):

Be carefull when concatenating two strings, you must use the dot (.) not the plus (+) sign

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that your column structure is INT.

Answer (score -2):

If non-numeric value encountered in your code try below one.
The below code is converted to float.

```
$PlannedAmount = ''; // empty string ''

if(!is_numeric($PlannedAmount)) {
           $PlannedAmount = floatval($PlannedAmount);
 }

 echo $PlannedAmount; //output = 0
```

Answer (score -2):

in PHP if you use **+** for concatenation you will end up with this error. In php **+** is a **arithmetic** operator.
 https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

**wrong use of + operator:**

```
            "<label for='content'>Content:</label>"+
            "<textarea class='form-control col-xs-12' rows='7'cols='100' id='content' name='content'>"+$initcontent+"</textarea>'"+                 
            "</div>";
```

use **.** for concatenation

```
$output = "<div class='from-group'>".
            "<label for='content'>Content:</label>".
            "<textarea class='form-control col-xs-12' rows='7'cols='100' id='content' name='content'>".$initcontent."</textarea>'".                 
            "</div>";
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to verify that you are dealing with a number:

```
 if (is_numeric($item['quantity'])) {
 if (is_numeric($product['price'])) {
    echo $item['quantity'] * $product['price'];
 } else {
    echo $item['quantity']. $product['price'];
 }
 } else {
    echo $item['quantity']. $product['price'];
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$sub_total += ($item['quantity'] * $product['price']);
```

replace by:

```
$sub_total += floatval($item['quantity']) * floatval($product['price']);
```