# SQL workaround for A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php

I see that there's an issue with `PHP` showing the following error:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in  on line

This is my code, I just want to pull an **entry** from the **database** with a **unique ID number**.

```
include("database_connection_information.php");     
$article_id = 2;
$sql = "SELECT article_title, article_text 
        FROM Articles 
        WHERE article_id = " + intval($article_id);
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

This code as it is generates the error.

([Warning: A non-numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered) describes the issue, but doesn't say how to work around it)

Comment: replace the plus sign with a period. This isn't JS/C, it's PHP. Unless you're wanting to do math here on a column that is anything other than an integer.

Comment: For starter, since this isn't javascript, concatenation is done with a dot `.` not with a plus `+`.

Comment: You should also read up on [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) so that you can prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @ObsidianAge He's using intval(), so there's no need for a prepared statement.

Comment: Good to know; didn't realise `invat()` negated the need for parameterisation :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge too bad there's no "syntax" highlight for sarcasm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is necessary to merge with a dot, not with a plus.

```
include("database_connection_information.php"); 

$article_id = 2;
$sql = "SELECT article_title, article_text 
        FROM Articles 
        WHERE article_id = ".$article_id;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had already tried using a dot instead of a plus, but with a dot the code stops working at that point, and doesn't process anything after that point.