# “Warning: A non-numeric value encountered” error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting an error while running view counter:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\tepetaklak\wp-content\themes\gridlove\core\template-functions.php
>   on line 163

Here is the code :

```
case 'views':
                global $wp_locale;
                $thousands_sep = isset( $wp_locale->number_format['thousands_sep'] ) ? $wp_locale->number_format['thousands_sep'] : ',';
                if ( strlen( $thousands_sep ) > 1 ) {
                    $thousands_sep = trim( $thousands_sep );
                }
/*line163*/ $meta = function_exists( 'ev_get_post_view_count' ) ?  number_format_i18n( absint( str_replace( $thousands_sep, '', ev_get_post_view_count( get_the_ID() ) ) + gridlove_get_option( 'views_forgery' ) ) )  . ' '.__gridlove( 'views' ) : '';
                break;
```

Thanks for support.

Comment: which one of this lines is 163?

Comment: @aidinMC $meta = function_exists( 'ev_get_post_view_count' ) ?  number_format_i18n( absint( str_replace( $thousands_sep, '', ev_get_post_view_count( get_the_ID() ) ) + gridlove_get_option( 'views_forgery' ) ) )  . ' '.__gridlove( 'views' ) : '';
                break;

Comment: i edited the code you can look up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: A non-numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (cast string to int)

```
$num = (int) (str_replace( $thousands_sep, '', ev_get_post_view_count( get_the_ID() ) )) + (int)(gridlove_get_option( 'views_forgery' ));
$meta = function_exists( 'ev_get_post_view_count' ) ?  number_format_i18n( absint( $num ) )  . ' '.__gridlove( 'views' ) : '';
```

Comment: @ErenArıcı  your welcome, if this answer did help you , please check it as true answer (below votes)

Answer (score 1):

Have you install php7.1 or greater?

From what type is `gridlove_get_option( 'views_forgery' )` ?

And you must convert the result from `str_replace` to an integer, if you use php7.1 or greater.+
**Edit:**

Your code should like this

```
$meta = function_exists( 'ev_get_post_view_count' ) ?  number_format_i18n( absint( (int)str_replace( $thousands_sep, '', ev_get_post_view_count( get_the_ID() ) ) + (int)gridlove_get_option( 'views_forgery' ) ) )  . ' '.__gridlove( 'views' ) : '';
```