# I am not able to get the product id in php strlen()

Tags: php, web

```
<?php  
  $name = "product_"
  $lens = strlen($name - 8); 
  $id = substr($name , 8 , $lens);
  $query = query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id= ".escape_string($id)." ");
?>
```

I want to take the id of product, but when I try it I see:

> A non-numeric value encountered in strlen($name - 8);

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: in the code you posted, there's no 'id', only 'product_' name

Comment: I think you should consider using `$id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $name);`

Comment: .... which will also save you the 'escape_string' since you know there are only digits in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean

```
$lens = strlen($name) - 8;
```

but you don't actually need `$lens`, because you can just do

```
$id = substr( $name, 8 );
```

That will automatically give you the remaining characters.

Now, the reason you are getting the warning, is [because of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044413). In other words, you are trying to subtract a number from a string:

```
$name - 8
```