# PHP return error: ErrorException in BookinginfoController.php line 101: A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, error-handling

> ErrorException in BookinginfoController.php line 101: A non-numeric value encountered

Here's the line of code

```
$ser_name=trim($ser_name,","); 
$price=trim($price,","); 
$sum+=$fet2[0]->price;
```

Heres full script

Line 99 is $ser_name=trim($ser_name,",");  Line 100 is $price=trim($price,","); Line is 101 $sum+=$fet2[0]->price;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: A non-numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered)

Comment: Maybe it should be `$user_name` in the first line? Typo?

Comment: where  is `101` ?

Comment: there are three lines of code. are they 101, 102, 103 or maybe 100, 101, 102 or even 99, 100, 101? please update you question. my guess would be that `$price` is not a number....

Comment: line 98:  $ser_name=trim($ser_name,",");

Comment: line 99 - $price=trim($price,",");             line 100 - $sum+=$fet2[0]->price;

Comment: Line 101 is $sum+=$fet2[0]->price;

Comment: $fet1 = DB::table('subservices')
         ->where('subid', '=', $id)
         ->get();
    $ser_name.=$fet1[0]->subname.'<br>';
    $ser_name.=",";     
    
    
    
    $fet2 = DB::table('seller_services')
         ->where('subservice_id', '=', $id)
         ->where('shop_id', '=', $neshopp)
         ->get();
    $price.=$fet2[0]->price.'<br>';
    $price.=","; 
    
        
    
    
    $ser_name=trim($ser_name,",");
    $price=trim($price,","); 
    $sum+=$fet2[0]->price;