# A non well formed numeric value encountered "php 7.1"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I encountered a problem with a non well formed numeric value. I encountered "php 7.1". date format

```
/**
 * @param integer $value
 * @param string $interval
 * @param string $in_date
 * @param string $format
 */
public function date_adds($value = 0, $interval = 'day', $in_date, $format = "Y-m-d")
{
    $t_split = explode('-', $in_date);
    $day = $t_split[2];
    $month = $t_split[1];
    $year = $t_split[0];

    if ($interval == 'day') {
        $day += (int) $value;
    } elseif ($interval == 'month') {
        $month += (int) $value;
    } elseif ($interval == 'year') {
        $year += (int) $value;
    }

    $date_add = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
    return date($format, $date_add);
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: What is `$t_split`? and/or what is `$interval`? The error message should be enough to go on, one of your values you are trying to do math with is not an integer.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: A non-numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered)

Comment: **arguments with default values must be at the end of the argument list**, i am talking about the `$in_date`,  you should follow some coding standards.