# A non-numeric value encountered on loop

Tags: php

I have this error appear on my script

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered
```

the line is :

```
$new_shipping_weight += $shipping_weight;
```

my code

```
if ($shipping_weight <= 0 || is_null($shipping_weight)) $shipping_weight = 0.1;

var_dump(is_numeric($shipping_weight));

$new_shipping_weight += $shipping_weight;

var_dump(is_numeric($new_shipping_weight));
```

result :

```
bool(true) 


Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in 


bool(true)
```

Where is the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Dear joe, Please follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044413/1193179

Comment: What is `$new_shipping_weight` before your code?

Comment: Move or copy the `is_numeric($new_shipping_weight)` check before the assignment. That may be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `$new_shipping_weight += $shipping_weight` expands to

```
$new_shipping_weight = $new_shipping_weight + $shipping_weight;
```

Thus both operators have to be non-numeric. Most likely `$new_shipping_weight` is not numeric before the assignment. It will be considered as `0`, but the warning issued to make you aware.

Try this code and you will get the same result, with `$a` being non-numeric before and numeric after assignment. You will also see the warning:

```
$a = '';
$b = 1;
var_dump(is_numeric($a));
$a += $b;
var_dump(is_numeric($a));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$new_shipping_weight += is_numeric($shipping_weight);
```

try this one or 
    $new_shipping_weight = is_numeric($shipping_weight) + is_numeric($new_shipping_weight);

Comment: How can that be the correct solution? `is_numeric()` will return a boolean value, thus adding either 0 or 1 to `$new_shipping_weight` and not the actual value of `$shipping_weight`!

Comment: No! `set_type()` also returns a boolean value. As Joe outline in his question, `$shipping_weight` is already a numeric value. Therefor type change/cast should not be necessary.

Comment: u right sorry and right code : `$new_shipping_weight += (double) $shipping_weight;`