# PHP7.2 A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, php-7.2

the following part of my code worked fine under PHP7.0:

```
if (Config::LOG_LEVEL == 'debug' | 'basic' | 'light') {}
```

I have now updated to PHP7.2 and the following error message appears:

```
A non-numeric value encountered
```

does anyone have any idea how i can fix this bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: A non-numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered)

Comment: I just try to compare not to multiply

Comment: `Config::LOG_LEVEL` is probably an integer, and you are comparing it to a string. By the way, you are using bitwise operator on strings.

Comment: You CAN'T compare one value with a multiple of other values like that. You can only compare one value with **one** other value. If you need to check multiple values, you need to make multiple comparisons and connect them with an `OR` logical expression (`OR` or `||` in PHP).

Comment: _“the following part of my code worked fine under PHP7.0”_ - no, it didn’t: https://3v4l.org/urFQe - doesn’t even return true, when `Config::LOG_LEVEL` is (effectively) `basic` or `light`. _Only_ for `debug` this did what you thought it would to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by others already, the code won't work as expected (usage of bitwise operator).  Try `in_array()` instead.

```
in_array(Config::LOG_LEVEL, ['debug', 'basic', 'light'])
```

See https://3v4l.org/ScWH5

Comment: Thanks for the solution!