# Warning "A non-numeric value encountered" when using parentheses with LIMIT statement in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting a PHP warning when running a query in phpMyAdmin that includes both parentheses and a `LIMIT` statement. For example:

```
(SELECT * FROM tableA LIMIT 1)
```

The warning is:

```
A non-numeric value encountered
```

I am using PHP version 7.2 and MySQL 5.6.42 and phpMyAdmin version 4.9.0.1

What might cause this warning?

EDIT:

My issue is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered), because no matter which column or table I use, I get the same warning

EDIT2:
Because people asked for an actual `UNION` query:

```
(SELECT name FROM tableA LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT name FROM tableB LIMIT 1)
```

This was the scenario I encountered the warning.

Comment: Why do you use parenthesis for this query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: A non-numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered)

Comment: I am not using this particular query. I encountered the warning when performing a `UNION` in which I use a `LIMIT` statement in both subqueries, which is why I need to use parentheses

Comment: @AlirezaA2F I also get the warning if I only ask for a string column in the `SELECT`, e.g. `(SELECT name FROM tableA LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Then post the UNION query.

Comment: Please add your php code to your post.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I think this is not necessary, because it does not add more info to the question. I encountered that all statements I am doing (no matter which table I use or which column), whenever I have parentheses with a `LIMIT` statment I am getting this warning

Comment: Well.. I can reproduce the issue with a valid UNION query.. It's clearly a bug in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @PaulSpiegel OK... So nothing much I can do about it (?)

Comment: It's a warning - You still get the result right? In the phpMyAdmin demo I can click on "Ignore". If you want to be a "good citizen", you should report the bug.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes, I am getting the results. Do you think it is a phpMyAdmin problem or a PHP 7.x issue (as explained in the linked thread)? Depending on what it is I would report it.

Comment: IMHO it's a bug in phpMyAdmin. If there is a problem with PHP, they (the phpMyAdmin developers) can report it to the PHP devs.

Comment: It sounds like phpMyAdmin wasn't updated to be compatible with this change in PHP 7.x.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel How could you reproduce my issue? Because I am not able reproducing it on phpmyadmin's demo server for them to see the warning

Comment: The demo doesn't work for me right now - so I can't run the test again. I used [this query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4a32753f7cd57b4ad76342187239dbe5)