# adding month-totals to year totals

Tags: php

A script written for php5.5 throws an error on this part of the script:

The script should give me the totals of rain amounts in comparison to other months and years, and the same for the temperature trends.

on this site you can see the correct working page: https://www.leavening.org/wdisplay/raintemptrending.php

My server recently upgraded to PHP7.1, i have numerous scripts running and the major part is fixed, but this one keeps puzzling me.

```php
  $alltimeaverage = $avtempjan+$avtempfeb+$avtempmar+$avtempapr+$avtempmay+$avtempjun+$avtempjul+$avtempaug+$avtempsep+$avtempoct+$avtempnov+$avtempdec;
  $avtempalltime = $alltimeaverage / 12;
  $avtempalltime = round($avtempalltime,2);
  echo "$avtempalltime" . $uomTemp;
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /customers

Comment: This is what the page looks like on my site: <https://www.akker.be/wxglobalwarming.php>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: A non-numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered)

Comment: Your variables are backwards. In the first line, you're adding all the months but storing it in `$alltimeaverage` but that's not that the average, that's `avtempalltime`

Comment: I read that post but could not figure out the solution for my problem..

Comment: I solved the problem by putting a float before every monthaverage.