# PHP 7.2 getting Warning: A Non-Numeric Value Encountered with numeric and decimal value

Tags: php

I have migrated **PHP** `5.0` To **PHP** `7.2`, I have retried to display values of  variables but i got `Warning: A Non-Numeric Value Encountered`.

I have couples of variables and each variables have specific value something like.

`$getProductPrice` have **37.95** , `$product_quanity`= **4** and `$productWeight` = **1.5**

I used following script for fix this but still getting same error.

```
$productWeight = $getProductData['weight'];
$product_quanity = $product_quanity;
$getProductPrice = $getProductData['price'];

if (is_numeric($getProductPrice) && is_numeric($product_quanity)) {
    $totalProductPrice +=  (int) $getProductPrice * (int) $product_quanity;
    $totalProductWeight +=  (int) $productWeight * (int) $product_quanity;
}
```

But it always return **Warning: A Non-Numeric Value Encountered** I have also tried to use `is_float()` and also tried to set all variables values as `0` before start loop but not work getting `Warning`.

Someone have any idea about this it's happened in PHP version 7.2 ?

Comment: You can find the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered

Comment: @MuhammedShihabudeenLabbaA i already referred this link but still getting warnings

Comment: you can use intval($your_variables) and wrap this into a function so no matter what php will always convert your variable into a valid int value.

Comment: @BlackXero, I used intval() but still getting same error

Comment: Probably `$productWeight` is not what you think it is…?

Comment: `if` is not a loop, it's a condition opening a branch. You nowhere check `$productWeight` for being a number, you only assume it.