# Warning : A non-numeric value encountered & Fatal error : Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to filter the products that have size Like S, M, L

[image: frontend]

This table is a product table

```
id | size
------------
 1 | S,M
 2 | S,M,L
 3 | S
 4 | M,L
```

This is the Shirtsize database structure:

```
id | size
------------
 1 | S
 2 | M
 3 | L
```

I have SQL problem to get these values.

```
if(isset($_POST["size"]))
{
    $size_filter = implode('|', $_POST["size"]);
    $s = implode(',', $_POST["size"]);
    echo $query .= ' AND size rlike "^'.($size_filter).'" AND  size like('%".$s."%')';
   // $query .= 'AND  size like('%".$s."%')';   
}
```

I used this SQL query it's working in PHPMyAdmin but product no displayed in the frontend

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = '1' AND size rlike "^M" OR size like('%M%')    

SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = '1' AND size rlike "^M|L" OR size like('%M|L%')
```

This query working only in PHPMyAdmin but use that in localhost frontend got this error

```
Warning : A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\DU\fetch_data.php on line 28 
Warning : A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\DU\fetch_data.php on line 28 
Fatal error : Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\DU\fetch_data.php:28 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
```

[image: phpmyadmin]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: A non-numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered)

Comment: What is on line 28 of file C:\xampp\htdocs\DU\fetch_data.php ?

Comment: echo $query .= ' AND size rlike "^'.($size_filter).'" AND  size like('%".$s."%')';

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Now i just test the code i will change code after i altered everything.

Comment: You need to start over. There's no point fixing this if you need to rewrite everything.

Comment: ok thank you for this kindly advice and give me some answer also bro.