# PHP Warning in Magento 2 "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered"

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm getting the following warning when trying to print order in Magento 2

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

It points to line 336 of an extension I'm using. Line 336 contains

```
 $this->lastPageFooterHeight = $fotterHeight + $elementGroupHeight;
```

As far as I'm aware, there shouldn't be any numerical values on this line. Some research suggests the issue could be with the + in the line. I've also read if could actually be down to the PHP version I'm using (7.3). Can anyone advise?

Comment: [Have you researched the error message before asking the question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered#answer-42044413) Seems like one of the variables (`$fotterHeight` or `$elementGroupHeight`) is not set or cant be combined with the plus operator. What can you do now? Either kindly ask the author of the extension to update his extension to work properly with your current php version. Or update the extension yourself (I know you shouldnt update core/extension files, but its necessary sometimes to adjust it to your needs).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: A non-numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately I no longer get upgrades for that extension so suspect there may already be an updated version (but at the price of it, I don't think this function alone is worth it). Also wouldn't really know where to start upgrading it myself (I know 0 PHP)