# A non-numeric value encountered with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I hope you're well. I'm trying to display a message with the search value I've done (I have 3 filed for a search : keyword, article type and date).
I have a function inside my Controller :

```
    public function page_liste_resultat_recherche_article(Request $request)
    { 
      $recherche_effectuer = request()->query('rechercher');
      $type_article_recherche = request()->query('type_article');
      $date_rechercher = request()->query('date');
      $article_rechercher = Article::withTrashed()->when($recherche_effectuer, function($query, $recherche_effectuer){
        return $query->where('titre', 'like', "%{$recherche_effectuer}%");
      })
        ->when($type_article_recherche, function($query, $type_article_recherche){
           return $query->where('type_article_id', 'like', "%{$type_article_recherche}%");
      }) 
        ->when($date_rechercher, function($query, $date_rechercher){
           return $query->where('created_at', 'like', "%{$date_rechercher}%");
      })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);

    if((empty($recherche_effectuer)) && (empty($type_article_recherche)) && ($date_rechercher)){
        $message_resultat_recherche = "Résultat pour la date " + ($date_rechercher) + " :";

    } elseif((empty($recherche_effectuer)) && (!empty($type_article_recherche)) && (empty($date_rechercher))){
         $message_resultat_recherche = "Résultat pour le type d'article " + ($type_article_recherche) + " :";

    } elseif((empty($recherche_effectuer)) && (!empty($type_article_recherche)) && (!empty($date_rechercher))){
        $message_resultat_recherche = "Résultat pour la date " + ($date_rechercher) + " et le type d'article " + ($type_article_recherche) + " :";

    } elseif((!empty($recherche_effectuer)) && (empty($type_article_recherche)) && (empty($date_rechercher))){
        $message_resultat_recherche = "Résultat pour le mot cle " + ($recherche_effectuer) + " :";

    } elseif((!empty($recherche_effectuer)) && (empty($type_article_recherche)) && (!empty($date_rechercher))){
        $message_resultat_recherche = "Résultat pour le(s) mot(s) clé(s) " + ($recherche_effectuer) + " et pour la date " + ($date_rechercher) + " :";

    } elseif((!empty($recherche_effectuer)) && (!empty($type_article_recherche)) && (empty($date_rechercher))){
        $message_resultat_recherche =  "Résultat pour le(s) mot(s) clé(s) " + ($recherche_effectuer) + "et le type d'article " + ($type_article_recherche) + " :";

    } elseif((!empty($recherche_effectuer)) && (!empty($type_article_recherche)) && (!empty($date_rechercher))){
        $message_resultat_recherche =  "Résultat pour le(s) mot(s) clé(s) " +($recherche_effectue) + ", le type d'article " + ($type_article_recherche) + " et la date " + ($date_rechercher) + " :";
    } else {
        $message_resultat_recherche = "Vous n'avez saisi aucune donnée";
    }
                
    return view('admin/article/admin_liste_resultat_recherche', [
        'articles' => $article_rechercher,
        'resultat' => $message_resultat_recherche
    ]);
}
```

Inside my view I show this :

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <p class="text-center mt-3">{{$resultat}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've this error :

```
A non-numeric value encountered
```

Did someone see where I'm wrong please ?

Cordially

Comment: `"Résultat pour la date " + ($date_rechercher) + " :"` looks like a non-PHP style string concatenation. Just a reminder. String concatenations in PHP are done with `.` not `+` as in most other languages so the correct way would be `"Résultat pour la date " . ($date_rechercher) . " :"`

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing some java project and thats how we do it in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Warning: A non-numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered)

As @apokryfos said in a comment, don't concatenate strings with `'+'` sign. Use `'.'` instead.

i.e

```
// Use...
echo "Hello". " world! ". 508;

// Instead of...
echo "Hello"+ " world! "+ 508;
```