# getting a warning on php website Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\InventoryMS\dashboard.php on line 15

Tags: php, mysql

I downloaded a website from github and it's working fine except that it is showing warning in dashboard like this:
[dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJfGN.png)

I want to know how to solve this. Here's the code of dashboard and line 15:

```
<?php require_once 'includes/header.php'; ?>

<?php 
    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE status = 1"; 
$query = $connect->query($sql); 
$countProduct = $query->num_rows;
    
$orderSql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_status = 1";
$orderQuery = $connect->query($orderSql); 
$countOrder = $orderQuery->num_rows;
    
$totalRevenue = ""; 
while ($orderResult = $orderQuery->fetch_assoc()) {     
    $totalRevenue += $orderResult['paid'];   //line 15 
}
    
$lowStockSql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE quantity <= 3 AND status = 1";
$lowStockQuery = $connect->query($lowStockSql); 
$countLowStock = $lowStockQuery->num_rows;
    
$userwisesql = "SELECT users.username , SUM(orders.grand_total) as
totalorder FROM orders INNER JOIN users ON orders.user_id =
users.user_id WHERE orders.order_status = 1 GROUP BY
orders.user_id";
$userwiseQuery = $connect->query($userwisesql);
$userwieseOrder = $userwiseQuery->num_rows;

$connect->close();

?>
```

Here's the database table orders:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2iF6.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: A non-numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting with `$totalRevenue = 0;` instead, then you're not trying to add a number to a string in the subsequent loop.

I'd guess this code was written for an older version of php which was more forgiving about mismatches between data types.