# $var is valid unix timestamp

Tags: php, validation, timestamp

I need a function to validate if the content of a variable is a valid unix timestamp.

I've checked this thread: [Check whether the string is a unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524680/check-whether-the-string-is-a-unix-timestamp) but the problem is that the function in the most voted answer still can cause some errors, for eg:

```
function is_timestamp($timestamp)
{
   return ((string) (int) $timestamp === $timestamp)
   && ($timestamp <= PHP_INT_MAX)
   && ($timestamp >= ~PHP_INT_MAX);
}

// Some tests:
$timestamp = 1289216307;
var_dump(is_timestamp($timestamp));
var_dump(date('Y-m-d', $timestamp));

// result
bool(false)
string(10) "2010-11-08" 

$timestamp = '20101108';
var_dump(is_timestamp($timestamp));
var_dump(date('Y-m-d', $timestamp));

// result
bool(true)
string(10) "1970-08-21"
```

Here, the first should be **TRUE** and the second should be **FALSE** so, what's the best way to test if a `$var` is a real valid unix timestamp?

Comment: The requirement of the OP in the linked question was to validate whether the **string** was a valid timestamp. Your first example passes an **integer**, so it will return false obviously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Here, the first should be TRUE and the second should be FALSE

Why? `20101108` is a valid UNIX timestamp, - as you say, it's August 21, 1970. Could well be a person's birthday for example.

The only way to achieve what you want is to set a range of dates that mark a "sane" timestamp by the definition you are working with - e.g. anything after January 1st, 2000 - and do a check against that.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I've saw the 1970 and I assume it was wrong, my bad.

Comment: @mjsilva I understand your requirement, but I think you have to make sure no `yyyymmdd` type date makes it into your system in the first place. There is no reliable way to tell timestamps and date strings apart

Answer (score 5):

You can check unix timestamp format using regular expression when your timestamp is bigger than size of integer:

```
/**
 * Check if timestamp is in unix format.
 * 
 * @param string $timestamp
 *   Target timestamp that will be checked.
 * 
 * @return bool
 *   TRUE if timestamp is in unix format. FALSE on failure.
 */
function is_unix_timestamp($timestamp) {
   return preg_match('/^\d+$/', $timestamp);
}
```

Comment: Sweet Lord, no.  There is no need to use regex.  `return ctype_digit ($timestamp)` seems a logical/direct call.

Answer (score 4):

A workaround for this would be to check if [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/strtotime) recognises the string as a valid date string.

```
function is_timestamp($timestamp)
{
   return ((string) (int) $timestamp === $timestamp)
   && ($timestamp <= PHP_INT_MAX)
   && ($timestamp >= ~PHP_INT_MAX)
   && (!strtotime($timestamp));
}
```

This will weed out strings that are probably date strings rather than timestamps.  It is probably easier to code than writing your own sanity checks.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own ;)

Some things you could check:

- Is the given parameter an int? if not => false
- Is it negative or above max? => false
- Everything else is true

This would work for your given tests.

Comment: Wouldn't work: the OP would like to recognize `20101108` as a date string, not a timestamp

Comment: @Pekka: `20101108` is given as a string, not an int, thus it would return `FALSE` as requested.

Answer (score -1):

Any number is potentially a timestamp. The only significant difference between your two examples is that the latter case is a string. In which case:

```
function is_timestamp($timestamp) {
    return is_int($timestamp) || is_float($timestamp);
}
```

(`is_numeric` is no good as it also returns true for strings that can be parsed as numbers.)