# How to identify a unix timestamp from a date?

Tags: php, regex, timestamp

Any ideas how I can make a simple `IF-statement` that sort `31-10-2017` or `12-01-2016` from `1511431687`?

I am converting from a set date, to use unix timestamp, and need a solution to sort out what is what. I want to display the date in human readable format (days/ month/year).

So I have a `$data` that is inside a loop. It pulls the date from a flat file. The old stuff has just saved the date as a date. For instance `31-10-2017` (exactly like that).

Now I use unix timestamp. For instance `1511431687`.

I see people have used a simple IF-statement, but I can not use it as both are 10 units long. Else that would have worked well.

```
$data = // either a timestamp, or a date in this format: 31-10-2017

if (strlen($data) === 10) // it's a timestamp   
$data =  date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $data);
```

Comment: `if (strpos($data, '-') === false) // it's a timestamp` (assumes positive timestamps); adjust if you might have timestamps before the 1970 timestamp base date

Comment: So you're looking for a regex for date? Or timestamp? Timestamp is shorter, `\d{10}`.

Comment: @RolandStarke: OP wrote _both are 10 units long_, so both are the same length. At least in this case.

Comment: @MarkBaker https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/hey-you-yeah-you-post-your-answers-as-answers-not-comments/296481#296481 You are not seeking clarification, you are providing a solution.  Please post in the correct location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$var is valid unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123541/var-is-valid-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe naive, but a solution might be to check if $data has a numeric value.

```
if (is_numeric($data)) { // it's a timestamp   
    $data =  date("d-m-Y H:i:s", (int) $data);
}
```

Comment: Note that "+0123.45e6" *is numeric*  too…

Comment: is a hyphen ( - ) a numeric value?

Comment: @deceze OP stated he only has to distinguish between a date string and a unix timestamp

Comment: @Preben no, it's not.  php -r "var_dump(is_numeric('-'));"

Comment: @Preben Only at the very start of an otherwise numeric the string (e.g. `-42`).

Comment: @l-x, yes. I need only distinguish between two formats: unix timestamp or a date format like 01-12-2017 or 02-11-2018

Comment: @l-x Sure, just pointing it out. `ctype_digit` would be more appropriate IMO.

Comment: @deceze `ctype_digit` needs *every* character in the input to be numeric. `ctype_digit('-42') === false`, so valid negative unix timestamps would not be recoginzed

Comment: Fair enough. If negative timestamps are supposed to be supported, then I concur.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) to check whether the string is all digits (probably a UNIX timestamp)
- [`preg_match('/^\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}$/', $date)`](http://php.net/preg_match) (either a d-m-Y or m-d-Y date)
- [`checkdate`](http://php.net/checkdate) to confirm whether a date you think you've identified is valid

Depending on how many different formats you expect, I'd try in this logical order:

- if `ctype_digit`, check if value is in expected range

  - if outside expected range, try dividing by `1000` (timestamps in milliseconds)
- otherwise, try matching with a regex in whatever formats you expect

  - confirm with `checkdate` that the values are sensible
- finally convert to `DateTime` object as standardised internal representation