# how to validate unix time with RegExp on PHP?

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check whether the string is a unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524680/check-whether-the-string-is-a-unix-timestamp)

i need validate a unix time with regexp on php.
Example:

```
<?php
is_unix( $unix )
{
    if( preg_match( '/([0-9]+)/' , $unix ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: Any number between zero and whatever `time()` produces is valid

Comment: Your RegEx only checks if there's at least a single occurance of a digit in your variable. To check the whole value you can use `/^\d+$/` (to make sure it checks from the beginning of the string till the end) or cast the value into an int and check if both are equal: `(int)$unix == $unix`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
function is_unix($t) {
    if ( is_numeric($t) && 0<$t && $t<strtotime("some date in the future that you don't expect the value to exceed, but before year 2038") ) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
}
```

Comment: replace `some date in the future that you don't expect the value to exceed` with [the year 2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)?