# strtotime and checking if valid timestamp

Tags: php

I am experiencing an issue with strtotime.

```
$data['task_time_due'] = strtotime("+1 day");
```

This returns false..

```
$this->Utility->is_timestamp_valid($data['task_time_due'])
```

Utility.php..

```
function is_timestamp_valid($timestamp)
{
    return ((string) (int) $timestamp === $timestamp) 
    && ($timestamp <= PHP_INT_MAX)
    && ($timestamp >= ~PHP_INT_MAX);
}
```

Anyone know why? This function works great throughout my application.

Comment: Why are you casting the return of your function by both `string` **and** `int`?

Comment: Because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524680/check-whether-the-string-is-a-unix-timestamp

Comment: Have you set the default timezone setting in `php.ini` or with `date_default_timezone_set()`?

Comment: @D4V1D the timezone is set with date.timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Cause strtotime returns `int` and you are comparing it strictly with string. Change this `(string) (int) $timestamp === $timestamp` to this `(int)(string) $timestamp === $timestamp`