# Validate a timestamp value in laravel 5

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I'm writing validator rules for checking if the data is valid before adding a new Eloquent model record.

It's quite clear with strings, decimals and integers.

But what about a timestamp field?

I added the column using `timestamp` method in one of my DB migrations, it works just fine. The only thing I need is to make sure the passed value will be a valid timestamp before executing the query.

Is there a direct/simple way or should I write a regexp for that?

Thank you

Comment: If there is one, I haven't seen it. I use a regex.

Answer (score 9):

I think that validate  like this..

```
$rules = ['start_at' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'];
```

Let's test this rule

```
public function testSimpleTimeStampValidation()
{

    $data = ['start_at'  => '2015-12-1 12:12:58'];


    $rules = ['start_at' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'];

    $validator = \Validator::make($data, $rules);

    $this->assertTrue($validator->passes()); // passed !        
}
```

Again trying test with unwanted date format..

```
public function testSimpleTimeStampValidation()
{

    $data = ['start_at'  => '12-1-2015 12:12:58'];


    $rules = ['start_at' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'];

    $validator = \Validator::make($data, $rules);

    $this->assertTrue($validator->passes()); // Failed !        
}
```

It looks this rules works very well..

more details [Data Format Validation in L5](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-date-format)

Comment: this might work. I have to return to this issue some time and see what I've done almost 2 months ago. Thanks

Comment: I have tested ın PHPUnit Test. I sure that "date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s" rules works too

Answer (score 5):

Use this rule

```
   public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'date_time' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) to parse the timestamp for you then run your validation in nice human-readable methods:

```
$date = Carbon::createFromTimeStamp( (int) $timestamp );
$min = Carbon::create( 2014, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59 );
$max = Carbon::create( 2015, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59 );
return $date->gt( $min ) && $date->lte( $max );
```

For actually validating the raw timestamp itself though, there's not much I can come up with other than just doing the same thing as above with raw numbers:

```
return 1420030799 < $timestamp && $timestamp <= 1451566799;
```

but that's much more difficult to read and maintain than the Carbon method.

Answer (score -1):

There is no validation rule for timestamps in laravel.
If you need to validate timestamps you can use somthing like that:

```
function isValidTimeStamp($timestamp)
{
    return ((string) (int) $timestamp === $timestamp) 
        && ($timestamp <= PHP_INT_MAX)
        && ($timestamp >= ~PHP_INT_MAX);
}
```

If you generate the timestamp in php there is no need to validate it. If it is a user input you could use the `date` validation rule of the [laravel validator](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#available-validation-rules) before you convert it into a timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a new validation rule in laravel to validate the timestamp...

```
Validator::extend('isTimeStamp', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return ((string) (int) $value === $value) 
           && ($value <= PHP_INT_MAX)
           && ($value >= ~PHP_INT_MAX);
});
```

You can now use `isTimeStamp` validation rule to validate timestamp.

Comment: What does `(string) (int)` do before `$value`?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova $value is considered a string, so first, you cast $value as an int (so "123" will become integer 123, but "a_string" will become integer 0). Then you cast again the previously casted value as a string again (so int 123 becomes "123"), and you compare this to the initial value, only a real int will still contain the initial value. Note that I would also cast (string)$value in this case. This is sourced from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524680/check-whether-the-string-is-a-unix-timestamp