# I want to disable edit button for next 24 hours when it is updated in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to disbale button for specific user for next 24 hours when that user click that button. In other words I want to add a funtion in admin panel where a user can't change price for next 24 hours.

```
$query = "select * from airport_parking where agent_id='$currentid'";
$run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$datafetch = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
$lastupdated = $datafetch['last_updated'];

<?php
    if($lastupdated >= 84600)
    {
        echo "<a href='edit-service.php?off_id=$currentid'><span class='btn btn-info'>Edit</span></a>";
}else{
     echo "<button class='btn btn-info' disabled>Edit</button>";
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: When user clicks on the button save the flag into database with current timing and check the time difference on every page login.

Comment: How can I save flag into a database?

Comment: what's the problem here?  This code should do what you want assuming 'last_updated' is the correct flag and updates when the button is clicked (which you don't show here, so I'm assuming that).  Do you mean how can I get a timestamp for the next 24 hours?

Comment: Why don't you compare with last updated timestamp with the current timestamp? 
What are the columns in your database? Is there any specific column that store the last updated datetime?

Comment: what is 84600 this value?

Comment: I think he meant 86400, which are the amount of seconds in a single day.

Comment: 86400 seconds in a day

Comment: last_updated is the value when user last time update prices

Comment: I updated date time in last_updated variable using now() function

Comment: You should just add 24 hr into your last_updated time and then apply your condition

Answer (score 1):

I'm making some assumptions here because your question isn't very complete.  Assuming that the $lastupdated is the last time the price was edited (and thus the starting point from which we have to wait 24 hours) then you just need to work out if the $lastupdated was more than 24 hours ago.  So you want (I think) to say something like

```
if((time() - $lastupdated) >= 84600)
    {
        echo "<a href='edit-service.php?off_id=$currentid'><span class='btn btn-info'>Edit</span></a>";
}else{
     echo "<button class='btn btn-info' disabled>Edit</button>";
 }
```

<------- edit ---->
If as the previous answer suggest this is specific to the user i.e. if user a updates he has to wait 24 hours, but 2 hours later user b can still update) you will need to check the last time each specific user updated as the other answer suggests

Answer (score 0):

You should tried like as below

```
$query = "select * from airport_parking where agent_id='$currentid'";
$run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$datafetch = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
$lastupdated = $datafetch['last_updated'];
$next24 = strtotime('+1 day', $next24); //add 24 hours in updated date
$current = time(); //get current date
<?php
    //check if current then is bigger then next 24 hours 
    if($current >= $next24)
    {
        echo "<a href='edit-service.php?off_id=$currentid'><span class='btn btn-info'>Edit</span></a>";
}else{
     echo "<button class='btn btn-info' disabled>Edit</button>";
 } 
 ?>
```

Make sure your dates are in unix timestamp,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524680/check-whether-the-string-is-a-unix-timestamp